# Query parser and optimizer for OSGi/LDAP filters/queries?

Tags: filter, ldap, osgi, optimization

I'm looking for a query parser and optimizer that can work with OSGi filter conditions, which are based on LDAP query syntax. Preferably something implemented in Java, but a different implementation (even web based) would be good too. My main use case is to feed it queries that maybe can be simplified.